# How to dynamically add values in jQuery selectbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I am currently using [jquery-selectbox](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) plugin 0.2.

I am unable to add values dynamically to the select box.

If I add dynamically the values are dispalyed, if I view the source code from browser, but it is not dispaying in ui.

I have read somewhere about `$("select").selectbox('option', options)` would do it, but I don't know what arguments to pass in it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you only need to regenerate the object with `$("#select_box_id").selectbox();`